# Title Bar with Fragment overlap with list view

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, layout, android-listview

I'm beginner in Android. I have a title bar which is separately placed in tool_bar.xml . Now i have two fragments. From one fragment i create a new activity which have to include tool_bar.xml (title bar). 
The problem is when i 'include' tool_bar.xml in newly create activty's xml file. The title bar overlaps with list-view.

I have also tried custom title bar method in On-create method but it didn't work. I think inclusion of tool_bar.xml will be the way but it overlaps with list-view.

Tool_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Activty_category_blogs.xml(XML of newly created activty)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:context="com.example.talha.test_fragement.Category_Blogs"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
<FrameLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Edited :

Oncreate Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Tab2.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String link = message + "?feed=titles";
    Log.d("ye category click krne par next activity me ye link bnta hy parsing ke liye",link);
    loadPage(link);
}
```

Log Cat Error of Null Object Reference :

```
2339-2339/com.example.talha.test_fragement E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.talha.test_fragement, PID: 2339
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.talha.test_fragement/com.example.talha.test_fragement.Category_Blogs}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:204)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
        at com.example.talha.test_fragement.Category_Blogs.onCreate(Category_Blogs.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

Comment: Can you attach your OnCreate() method?

Comment: Please check , i have edited

Comment: Ok, You have RelativeLayout as base layout. So, put in your frame layout attribute android:layout_below with id of your toolbar.

Comment: I have edited it like this but it stills overlaps:
<FrameLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@layout/tool_bar">

Answer (score 0):

In your OnCreate() method of your activity, you should be setting the toolbar for the current activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}
```

Activity_Category_Blogs layout will contain this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

tool_bar file will have the same toolbar used in your activity without the extra controls:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

In your fragment OnCreate() method you should be able to set the text of textViewTitle:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle)).setText("XYZ");
```

Comment: It gives error on setSupportActionBar of cannot resolve method

Comment: Your activity also needs to extend AppCompatActivity like such: 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: it gives null boject reference. i have pasted the log cat error

Comment: You are getting null object reference error because you are trying to GetTitle() before you SetTitle()

Comment: Could you please tell where to use setTitle()

Comment: You are using fragments, so you can set title when fragment is created:

item = new ExampleFragment();
item.setTitle("ExampleFragment");

It is difficult to say, as I can not see your code

Comment: This is newly created activity from 2nd fragment. Is there any method so that i could fix the text in toolbar to "XYZ"

Comment: I couldn't understand the above edit. Could you please explain it . 
android:text="XYZ" didn't do the work  in tool_bar.xml

Comment: Added edit, explained as much as possible without seeing your application, hopefully it is useful.

Comment: The two fragment contain the word "XYZ" in the toolbar.. but this newly created activty doesn't. Please twll me what code do you want me to see. so you could help in this difficulty

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:context="com.example.talha.test_fragement.Category_Blogs"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        />


    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

</RelativeLayout >
```