# Custom Adapter on applying on list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, custom-adapter

I have made a custom Adapter and populate it with the data. I have used Logcat to see whether the array i'm passing to custom Adapter class contains the data and it does.
The error i got is following. It occurs when this CategoryBlog is created. Activity is created but it does not contain list view

```
 exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

'mainblogpost' contains the array with all the data i want to populate with.
'MainListActivityAdapter' is the Adapter Class.
'Category_Blogs' is the class where i want to set the list view.

**Category_Blog.java**

I don't add import statement. there is no error in it

```
public class Category_Blogs extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.talha.appforblog.MESSAGE";
List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> mainBlogPost = new ArrayList<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>();
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private AbsListView mListView;
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Tab2.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String link = message.trim() + "?feed=titles";
    Log.d("ye category click krne par next activity me ye link bnta hy parsing ke liye",link);
    loadPage(link);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category__blogs, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void loadPage(String link) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadpage me a gae nh");
    // if((sPref.equals(ANY)) && (wifiConnected || mobileConnected)) {
    new DownloadXmlTask(this).execute(link);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>> {
    private Context mContext;

    public DownloadXmlTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", "" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> results) {
        if (results != null) {
            try {
                String title, link, image, pubDate;
                Log.d("test", "onpost");
                // custom array adapter
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry result : results) {
                    title = result.title;
                    link = result.link;
                    image = result.image;
                    pubDate = result.pubDate;
                    HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    blogPost.put("link", link);
                    blogPost.put("title", title);
                    blogPost.put("image", image);
                    blogPost.put("pubDate", pubDate);
                    blogPosts.add(blogPost);
                }
                // copying to main item List array
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    mainBlogPost.add(results.get(i));
                }
                Log.d("fff", results.get(1).pubDate);
                MainListActivityAdapter mAdapter =
                        new MainListActivityAdapter(Category_Blogs.this, mainBlogPost);
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                //((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

                // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(Category_Blogs.this);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("test", "exception: "+e);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        // Instantiate the parser
        StackOverflowXmlParser stackOverflowXmlParser = new StackOverflowXmlParser();
        List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> entries = null;
        String title = null;
        String url = null;

        try {
            //opening the connection and fetching
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            entries = stackOverflowXmlParser.parse(stream);
            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", "" + e);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
        for (StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry entry : entries) {
            Log.d("aaa",entry.pubDate);
        }

        return entries;
    }
  private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();

        return conn.getInputStream();
    }

}
```

}

**MainListActivityAdapter.java**

```
public class MainListActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> mainBlogPost = new ArrayList<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>();
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MainListActivityAdapter(Activity a, List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> main) {
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mainBlogPost = main;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mainBlogPost.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    Log.d("test", "fetching" + position);
    String tit = mainBlogPost.get(position).title;
    String cate = mainBlogPost.get(position).pubDate;
    String pub = mainBlogPost.get(position).pubDate;
    String image_url = "http://download.androidhive.info/img/btn_fb_login.png";
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView cat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.category); // category
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // image
    TextView publish = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.pubDate); // publish date

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(tit);
    cat.setText(cate);
    publish.setText(pub);
    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(image_url)
            .into(image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Activity_category_blog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:context="com.example.talha.test_fragement.Category_Blogs"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
<FrameLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@layout/tool_bar">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you are not calling findViewById for the ListView

Comment: could you please mention what to call and where.

Comment: onCreate, after setContentView

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.);
 What to add in it

Comment: the listview should be defined in activity_category__blogs.xml. And you have to use the id *you* assigned

Comment: I have pasted the xml fileof category blog. Please check it .

Comment: use `android.R.id.list`

Comment: Thank you very very much.
f you could help in just one more thing:
Could please give the answer of it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118440/title-bar-with-fragment-overlap-with-list-view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97128/discussion-between-user3585510-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 0):

```
 You fail to initialize the listview.

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
**listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);**
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Tab2.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String link = message.trim() + "?feed=titles";
        Log.d("ye category click krne par next activity me ye link bnta hy parsing ke liye",link);
        loadPage(link);
    }
```

Comment: I have pasted the xml file. PLease check.. R.id.listView is not an option given by androidstudio

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvID);//where lvID is id from your listview placed in activity_category__blogs layout.
```

Comment: I have pasted the XML file.. I implement your answer but it didn't work. Please check

Comment: it is working. Your ListView is null, that is why you have NullPointerException when you try to use method setAdapter() on the null object reference, your listView. Just initialize it in onCreate and set id of yours ListView from your layout xml.